# Successfully displaying IMarkers in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm a complete newbie to Plugin Development, so I might have made a stupid mistake. I'm trying to develop a basic plugin that'll highlight selected lines based on outside input. For now, I'm just trying to get any lines to highlight at all. I've tried implementing a textmarker with the following code in an action:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
IResource resource = null;
if (editor != null){
    resource = extractResource(editor);
}
try {
    IMarker marker = createMarker((IFile) resource, 3);
} catch (CoreException e) {}
```

The `createMarker()` creates the IMarker and sets severity, line number, and message.

The `plugin.xml` defines the selected MARKER_TYPE as of type `org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker` and persistent. I've tried searching around but I can't figure out what to do to the marker to make some visible UI change after setting it. Nothing appears.

Comment: Please show the source of your `createMarker`!

Answer (score 0):

If you are highlighting errors, then you should also add `org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker` to maker super types, so it will be highlighter by the editor without additional efforts.

Otherwise, you should use `org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes` extension point to define the new annotation type for your marker type (which is actually displayed in the editor) and `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification` extension point to customize default visual representation of that annotation.